# Retrieve Dell current Bios Version

Tags: powershell, http, web-scraping

So I managed to write a powershell script that outputs a list of all computers in my domain with their bios version. Now the next task is to get the current BIOS Version of the respective laptops. With "current" I mean the version which Dell supports and recommends to update to.

The problem is I haven't found any API (maybe TechDirect?) and the only place where I can see the current bios version is on their support webpage. I tried to web scrape with Invoke-WebRequest

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$web = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.dell.com/support/home/de/de/debsdt1/product-support/servicetag/2mx4wz1/drivers"
```

at the first time trying this it worked but now i always returns this

`Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At C:\Users\l.engleder\Documents\Scraper.ps1:3 char:8
+ $web = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.dell.com/support/home/de/d ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand`

Thank you very much and I'm looking forward to learning from you

Answer (score 1):

Tried to do the same thing, but gave up on that, instead I've found another solution, dell has also this repository of downloads, they are all in the same format, and even better html based, so as long as they won't change the structure this is working for me.

http://downloads.dell.com/published/pages/

```
PS>$a = Invoke-WebRequest http://downloads.dell.com/published/pages/optiplex-3030-aio.html
PS>($a.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByTagName('div') | Where {$_.getAttributeNode('id').Value -eq 'Drivers-Category.BI-Type.BIOS'}).outerhtml.split('<')[26].Replace("TD","").replace(">","").trim()
PS>A14
```

it's not pretty and neat, but it works on all models that I've tested. as long as you use link from that main page, it will probably work for all models / links there.

-R